# What is the syntax for a repository in a custom PublishToIvyRepository task?

Tags: gradle, ivy

I am trying to create a custom task so that I can publish to a specific repository that is not normally part of the project-level `publishing {}` block in `build.gradle`. My initial thought was to create a task of type [`PublishToIvyRepository`](https://docs.gradle.org/4.4.1/javadoc/org/gradle/api/publish/ivy/tasks/PublishToIvyRepository.html), which has a field for a custom repository. My code looks like this:

```
task publishToSpecialIvyRepo(type: PublishToIvyRepository) {
    repository = ivy {
        url "http://example.com/mySpecialIvyRepo"
        layout 'pattern' , {
            artifact '[organization]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact](-[revision])(-[classifier]).[ext]'
            ivy '[organization]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact].[ext]'
        }
    }
    publication = project.publishing.publications[0]
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to work because I get an error message involving not recognizing the `ivy {}` syntax.

> Could not find method ivy() for arguments [build_6twdleybkcdvojdar8mcpb96g$_run_closure7$_closure23@60c8966b] on task ':MyProject:publishToSpecialIvyRepo' of type org.gradle.api.publish.ivy.tasks.PublishToIvyR
>   epository.

Unfortunately, the [documentation about publishing to Ivy repositories](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_ivy.html) doesn't describe writing your own `PublishToIvyRepository` task, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Is this the right approach to trying to publish to a specific repo? If so, then what am I doing incorrectly? Is there a better way to accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ivy` method is part of the `RepositoryHandler`, so it is not available in the `Project` or `PublishToIvyRepository` task scope.

You can try to create the repository via the default `RepositoryHandler`:

```
repository = repositories.ivy {
    // configure the repository
}
```

Please note, that this method will add the repository to the list of repositories used for artifact resolution.